dotnet ef migrations add fails on one DbContext succeeds on the other?
I am using EF Core v7.0.18.
I have a .csproj with 2 dBContext, GlobalDbContext and ConfiguratinDbContext.
GlobalDbContext works when I add a and EF migration - cmd lines below ConfigurationDbContext does not.
The error I get is:

Unable to create an object of type 'ConfigurationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

How to fix this? I have ensured that each has a Default [no parameters constructor]
For GlobalDbContext, this works and migration is created:
dotnet ef migrations add 
--project Doma.DataLayer/Doma.DataLayer.csproj 
--startup-project Doma.DataLayer.Tests/Doma.DataLayer.Tests.csproj 
--context Doma.DataLayer.Global.Models.GlobalDbContext 
--configuration Debug 
--framework net7.0 Initial 
--output-dir Global/Migrations

For ConfigurationDbContext - this is failing:
dotnet ef migrations add --project Doma.DataLayer/Doma.DataLayer.csproj 
--startup-project Doma.DataLayer.Tests/Doma.DataLayer.Tests.csproj 
--context Doma.DataLayer.Configuration.Models.ConfigurationDbContext 
--configuration Debug --framework net7.0 Initial 
--output-dir Configuration/Migrations
    Build started...
    Build succeeded.


Unable to create an object of type 'ConfigurationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
Process terminated with exit code 1

Succeeding DbContext [GlobalDbContext]:
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Doma.DataLayer.Global.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Doma.DataLayer.Global.Models;

public partial class GlobalDbContext : DbContext
{
    public GlobalDbContext()
    {
    }

    public GlobalDbContext(DbContextOptions<GlobalDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AppConfiguration> AppConfigurations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FormInstance> FormInstances { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FormValue> FormValues { get; set; }
   
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(
                "Data Source=TempGlobalDatabas.db");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AppConfiguration>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("AppConfiguration");

            entity.Property(e => e.AppConfigurationId).HasColumnType("varchar(36)");
            entity.Property(e => e.AppName).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.BucketName).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.Comments).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.ConfigurationIconPath).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.CurrentlyInstalledVersion).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.CurrentlyInstalledVersionLabel).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.ETag).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.FileKey).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.FileName).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.LastModified).HasColumnType("bigint");
            entity.Property(e => e.Title).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.Url).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.Version).HasColumnType("varchar");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<FormInstance>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("FormInstance");

            entity.Property(e => e.FormInstanceId).HasColumnType("varchar(36)");
            entity.Property(e => e.DateCreated).HasColumnType("bigint");
            entity.Property(e => e.FormId).HasColumnType("varchar(36)");
            entity.Property(e => e.FormInstanceName).HasColumnType("varchar");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<FormValue>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("FormValue");

            entity.Property(e => e.FormValueId).HasColumnType("varchar(36)");
            entity.Property(e => e.FormInstanceId).HasColumnType("varchar(36)");
            entity.Property(e => e.QuestionId).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.Type).HasColumnType("varchar");
            entity.Property(e => e.Value).HasColumnType("varchar");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
#nullable disable

Failing DbContext (ConfigurationDbContext):
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
    #nullable disable
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    namespace Doma.DataLayer.Configuration.Models;
    public partial class ConfigurationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    
        public ConfigurationDbContext()
        {
            
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<ApplicationSetting> ApplicationSettings { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Command> Commands { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<ContentLink> ContentLinks { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Form> Forms { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Glossary> Glossaries { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<GlossaryEntry> GlossaryEntries { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Grouping> Groupings { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Interface> Interfaces { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Link> Links { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Map> Maps { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<MapLocation> MapLocations { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<MapLocationType> MapLocationTypes { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<MatchingQuestionChoice> MatchingQuestionChoices { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<MultipleChoiceQuestion> MultipleChoiceQuestions { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<QuestionCategory> QuestionCategories { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<QuestionType> QuestionTypes { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Questionnaire> Questionnaires { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<QuestionnaireQuestionCategory> QuestionnaireQuestionCategories { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Rssfeed> Rssfeeds { get; set; }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(
                    "Data Source=Configuration.db");
            }
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(
                "Data Source=Configuration.db");
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationSetting>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.SettingId);
    
                entity.ToTable("ApplicationSetting");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.SettingId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.SettingDataType).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 50 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.SettingName).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 50 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.SettingValue).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Category");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (36)");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryActionIconImage).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (500)");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryAutoLaunch)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("1")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryExtendedAccordionListStyle).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (500)");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryHideGlobally)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("1")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryIconIsDefaultResource)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryImageUrl).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (140)");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryIsExpandable)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryLockAfterCompletion)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryOrder).HasColumnType("INT");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategorySelectedBackgroundColor).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (500)");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategorySequentialLock)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("1")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryShowChildrenSubtitles)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.CategoryTitle).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (140)");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Command>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Command");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.CommandId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.CommandAction).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 250 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.CommandImage).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 250 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Content>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Content");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.ContentId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.ContentBlockViewedTracking)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.ContentPages).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 140 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.ContentType).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 50 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.ContentUseAlternatePresentation)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.TargetId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentLink>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("ContentLink");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.ContentLinkId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.ContentId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.ContentLevel)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("1")
                    .HasColumnType("INT");
                entity.Property(e => e.ContentLinkOrder)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("1")
                    .HasColumnType("INT");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Document>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Document");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.DocumentId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.DocumentDisplayName).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 140 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.DocumentExtension).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 140 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.DocumentFileName).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 140 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.DocumentIsDefaultResource)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.DocumentLocation).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 140 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Email>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Email");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.EmailId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.EmailAddress).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 100 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Form>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Form");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.FormId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.FormAllowExport)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.FormName).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.FormPdfTemplateSource).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.FormTemplateSource).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Glossary>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Glossary");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.GlossaryId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.GlossaryName).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<GlossaryEntry>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("GlossaryEntry");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.GlossaryEntryId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.GlossaryEntryGlossaryId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.GlossaryEntryTerm).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.GlossaryEntryTermDefinition).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 8000 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Group>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Group");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.GroupId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR(36)");
                entity.Property(e => e.GroupFileKey).HasColumnType("VARCHAR(255)");
                entity.Property(e => e.GroupName).HasColumnType("VARCHAR(255)");
                entity.Property(e => e.GroupOrder).HasColumnType("INT");
                entity.Property(e => e.GroupParentId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR(255)");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Grouping>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Grouping");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.GroupingId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR(36)");
                entity.Property(e => e.GroupingHideUngroupedItems).HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.GroupingTitle).HasColumnType("VARCHAR(255)");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Image>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Image");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.ImageId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.ImageSource).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Interface>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Interface");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.InterfaceId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.InterfaceDbName).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 140 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.InterfaceTitle).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 140 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Link>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Link");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (36)");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkActionIconImage).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (500)");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkCourseEndPoint)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkDisableFavorites)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkExcludeFromSearchResults)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkHideNavigationControls)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkIsExpandable)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkIsHidden)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkNavigationPreventionMessage).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (1000)");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkOrder)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("1")
                    .HasColumnType("INT");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkParentId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (36)");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkSecondaryIconImage).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (500)");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkShowChildrenSubtitles)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkSubtitle).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (140)");
                entity.Property(e => e.LinkText).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (140)");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Map>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Map");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.MapId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapName).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 100 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapStartingDistance)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("DOUBLE");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapStartingLatitude)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("DOUBLE");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapStartingLongitude)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("DOUBLE");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapUseSplitView)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<MapLocation>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("MapLocation");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationAddress).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationChildMapId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationDescriptionSource).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationFeaturedImage).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationLabel).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationLatitude).HasColumnType("DOUBLE");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationLongitude).HasColumnType("DOUBLE");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationMapId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationPhoneNumber).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationStartingDistance).HasColumnType("DOUBLE");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationTypeId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationUrl).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<MapLocationType>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("MapLocationType");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationTypeId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationTypeName).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationTypeOrder).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MapLocationTypePinImage).HasColumnType("VARCHAR ( 255 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<MatchingQuestionChoice>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("MatchingQuestionChoice");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.MatchingQuestionChoiceId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MatchingQuestionChoiceAnswer).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MatchingQuestionChoiceQuestionId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MatchingQuestionChoiceText).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<MultipleChoiceQuestion>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("MultipleChoiceQuestion");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.MultipleChoiceQuestionId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MultipleChoiceQuestionAnswerA).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MultipleChoiceQuestionAnswerB).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MultipleChoiceQuestionAnswerC).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MultipleChoiceQuestionAnswerD).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MultipleChoiceQuestionAnswerE).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MultipleChoiceQuestionAnswerF).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.MultipleChoiceQuestionCorrectAnswer).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 50 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Note>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.NotesId);
    
                entity.Property(e => e.NotesId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.NotesHtml).HasColumnType("VARCHAR(10000)");
                entity.Property(e => e.NotesSource).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.NotesTargetId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Page>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Page");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.PageId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.PageLoadHomePageOnBackAction)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.PageLoadHomePageOnForwardAction)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.PageMarkViewedOnOpen)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.PagePreventCertificateAuthentication)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.PageSource).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 1000 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.PageText).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 5000 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Phone>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Phone");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.PhoneId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.PhoneNumber).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 50 )");
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Question>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Question");
    
                entity.Property(e => e.QuestionId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (36)");
                entity.Property(e => e.QuestionCategoryId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR (36)");
                entity.Property(e => 

......e.VideoId).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 36 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.VideoAutoPlay)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("1")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.VideoLoadHelpPageOnFinished)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.VideoLoadNextContentOnFinished)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("1")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.VideoMarkViewedOnOpen)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
                    .HasColumnType("BIT");
                entity.Property(e => e.VideoSource).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
                entity.Property(e => e.VideoTitle).HasColumnType("VARCHAR( 500 )");
            });
    
            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }
    
        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
    #nullable disable


GlobalDbContext is success because DbContextOptionsBuilder.Use** provider configuration API is called in overriding OnConfiguring (in your case is  UseSqlite). Another case is your startup project has a service container and the tool resole an instance of GlobalDbContext that has well configured.
In the ConfigurationDbContext, if I not wrong, the dotnet-ef tool cannot resolve any instance of it, so it create an instance via parameter-less constructor, and since no provider is configured, the exception is thrown as you see.
For more information, you can add --verbose argument to dotnet ef migrations to see the detailed log.
To resolve it, you can add ConfigurationDbContext to service container by using AddDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("your_connection_string")) or add override for OnConfiguring as you do in a separated partial class (to avoid lossing code after rescaffolding):
public partial class ConfigurationDbContext: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(
                "Data Source=TempGlobalDatabas.db");
        }
    }
}


